# Problem with Python dataclasses. Comparison between two values is not showing desired results

Tags: python, comparison

I tried to do some comparison with @dataclass between two Integer values. But it´s showing some weird results.

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class PersonNewSlry:
    sort_index: int = field(init=False)
    salary: int
    name: str 
    address: str
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sort_index = self.salary
    
        
p_slry_1 = PersonNewSlry(75000, "Max" , "Main St 123")
p_slry_2 = PersonNewSlry(75000, "Jules", "Main St 456")


print("== : ", p_slry_1 == p_slry_2)
print("<= : ", p_slry_1 <= p_slry_2)
print("<  : ", p_slry_1 < p_slry_2)
print(">= : ", p_slry_1 >= p_slry_2)
print(">  : ", p_slry_1 > p_slry_2)
```

Result is:

```
== :  False
<= :  False
<  :  False
>= :  True
>  :  True
```

I tried it with Python 3.10 and 3.8.8 but the results are the same.

I would expect the following results to come out:

```
== : True 
<= : True 
<  : False 
>= : True 
>  : False
```

I only get the desired results when I am doing the following:

```
name: str = field(compare=False)
address: str = field(compare=False)
```

I thought I could define the `__post_init__` method with the sort_index and compare the two values. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

There is no special meaning to `sort_index` - it is a field like any other. It will be taken into account when comparing, but so will the other fields that were not marked as non-comparing. Your tests are comparing `(75000, 75000, "Max", "Main St 123")` against `(75000, 75000, "Jules", "Main St 456")`; the first two elements of the tuple are equal so the result of the comparison depends on the third field, where `"Max" >= "Jules"`; therefore, `p_slry_1 >= p_slry_2`.

To define total order on a class, you must define the [six comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) (or just one comparison operator and an equality operator, then decorate your class with [`@functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)). In order for your class to be sortable, it is sufficient to only define `__lt__`.

With ordered dataclasses, these methods are generated for you; but you can override them. Alternately, you have to mark any fields you don't want to compare on, as you did in your last snippet.

Also note that your `sort_field` is not needed if `salary` is not marked as non-comparing. If `salary` is the only comparing field, then you will compare `(75000)` and `(75000)`. If you also have your `sort_order`, then you have two comparing fields with identical values: `(75000, 75000)` vs `(75000, 75000)`, for which I cannot find any use. Having a `sort_field` as the only comparing field would make sense if you want to have a criterion that is calculated from other fields, but not explicitly present; though at that point I would probably just define a new total ordering.