# Dataclass comparison methods giving unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I just learnt how dataclasses work and was messing with it, until I ran into a issue with the comparison logic, the first `print` prints `False`, even though it should print `True` as `overall` of `player1` is equal to `player2`.
Here is the code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(order=True)
class Player:
    overall: int = field(init=False)
    name: str
    player_class: str
    health: int
    damage: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.overall = self.health + self.damage


player1 = Player('Player1', 'Mage', 200, 400)
player2 = Player('Player2', 'Ranger', 300, 300)

print(player1 >= player2)  # prints False, even though it should print True.
print(player1 <= player2)  # prints True, as expected.
```

Why is this happening?
According to the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71700084/problem-with-python-dataclasses-comparison-between-two-values-is-not-showing-de) very similar post, the logic would be that the fields of both `player1` and `player2` are compared as tuples where order matters and the order is the order in which fields are defined in the dataclass, since `overall` is equal for both, it moves on to the next field, `name` and hence evaluates to `False`, but shouldn't it return `True` the instant both `overall` were evaluated to be equal?

Comment: player3?  Is this a Typo?

Comment: yes it is, my bad, the issue still exists with player2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how tuple inequalities work in Python: if the first element is equal, then Python looks at the second element and so on. So `player1 >= player2` is `False` because `'Player1' < 'Player2'`

If you want `<=` and `>=` to be based on only the value of `overall`, you could write:

```
@dataclass(order=True)
class Player:
    overall: int = field(init=False)
    name: str = field(compare=False)
    player_class: str = field(compare=False)
    health: int = field(compare=False)
    damage: int = field(compare=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.overall = self.health + self.damage
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It's also working..

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Player:
    name: str
    player_class: str
    health: int
    damage: int
    overall: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.overall = self.health + self.damage

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.overall == other.overall

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.overall < other.overall

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.overall <= other.overall

player1 = Player('Player1', 'Mage', 200, 400)
player2 = Player('Player2', 'Ranger', 300, 300)

print(player1 == player2)  
print(player1 <= player2)
```

Comment: I suggest you delete your other answer.

Comment: yes, action completed